# checksum code in obj-c

Tags: iphone

I am looking for checksum algorithm  written in obj-c so that I can validate a ticket(number) and generate 2Dbar code based on validation.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to validate an existing ticket numbering scheme, then you need to find out which checksum algorithm is used.

Comment: no first i need to code for ticket validation . so is there any available ticket code generation algo

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use a public-key cryptographic function.

Encrypt with the private key fixed length information, including a number (the real ticket number) and a random salt (to reduce the chance of someone cracking your key), into a fixed length output.

You can then use the public key to decode that output and verify that the information is there.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html) is some Apple sample code that demonstrates the use of cryptographic functions.

For 2D barcode code, you could start by looking at [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)